# React native detect if device is RTL

Tags: ios, react-native, right-to-left

If the user has set the device (ios) to a language that follows RTL how do I detect this in react native? I'm using the following to obtain the language.

`NativeModules.SettingsManager.settings.AppleLanguages[0]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `I18nManager` to check Right-to-Left.

First you should import `I18nManager` from `react-native`

```js
import {I18nManager} from 'react-native';
```

and then check isRTL constant

```js
console.log("is RTL", I18nManager.isRTL);
```

You might also want to read this blog post about RTL in react-native: [Right-to-Left Layout Support For React Native Apps](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2016/08/19/right-to-left-support-for-react-native-apps#making-an-app-rtl-ready)